# How do I specify a database name for a SQL DB Deploy task?

Tags: azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps, I'm trying to setup a SQL DB Deploy task as a part of a new release pipeline. Database Name is a required field for this task. However, the field is read only, so I cannot manually input it.

There is a tooltip stating that "This setting is linked to the 'Database name' (Parameters.DatabaseName) pipeline parameter." I'm not sure what this means, but it is perhaps the key to my solution.

I tried adding a Pipeline variable named DatabaseName and also Parameters.DatabaseName, but this did not help.

How can I specify a value for the Database Name property?

[image: SQL DB Deploy task screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Database Name is linked as a [Process Parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/parameters?view=azure-devops).

Under the "SQL Deployment" process, you should see the variable there in an editable state. You can either fill in the value there, or you can unlink and fill in the value in the "SQL DB Deploy" task.